# how to get jQuery on click or tap to both run the same function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get this jQuery listener on Click or Tap to run a function. Currently its working fine on click but the ripple effect currently doesn't want to run when tapped on mobile?

Is there a better alternative to '.on('click tap')' or am i just using it incorrectly and if so what an i doing wrong?

below is the code for the button with ripply effect.

```js
$( '.hvr-ripple-out' ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( 'fill' );
});


$( '.hvr-ripple-out' ).on( 'click tap', function() {
  var el = $(this),
    newone = el.clone(true);
  el.before(newone);
  el.remove();
  newone.addClass( 'fill' );
});
```

```css
.hvr-ripple-out {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hvr-ripple-out:hover {
  color: #39CCCC;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
}


@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}

.hvr-ripple-out:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) solid 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.hvr-ripple-out:hover:before,
.hvr-ripple-out:focus:before,
.hvr-ripple-out:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  border-color: #39CCCC;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fill {
  background-color: #39CCCC;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fill:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="padding: 100px; float: left;">
  <a class="hvr-ripple-out"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought mobile still propegated a click event?

Comment: @Doug, maybe i was just doing something wrong but it wasn't working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want functionality for mobile device's support, you need to implement jquery mobile:

The tap event is supported in jQuery mobile.

Add this code to your page. It's linking the JQuery mobile JavaScript file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```